# How to handle "unexpected preroll-complete"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avplayer, osx-yosemite

My app (OS X 10.10, Xcode 6.1.1) uses an `AVPlayerView` to show a video resource bundled inside the app. Normally the video runs as expected. Sometimes--and I haven't figured out a way to reliably reproduce this--the video does not start to play, and the screen is all black. At the same time, a warning pops up in the console:

```
<<<< Boss >>>> figPlaybackBossPrerollCompleted: unexpected preroll-complete notification
```

How can I programmatically recover from this? I tried Googling parts of the error description but there was only one result (an [email to the Apple Mailing List](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2014/Dec/msg00087.html)).

Perhaps a notification my view controller can listen for?

Alternatively, if you know a way I can force this state to reproduce, that would help too, as I could then put a breakpoint in.

UPDATE: I still haven't been able to force this problem to reproduce, but I have seen it a couple of times since the first post, and I can say for sure that it's not related to the NSNotifications `AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification`, `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification` or `AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification`. My View Controller is listening for those, and didn't hear them when the bug presented.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope. we did try some other solutions but nothing worked and the bug still presented seemingly at random. The solution I remember was an NSTimer that fired a "check if the video's actually playing" method every few seconds. I also remember noticing that when the screen went black, if I scrolled my mouse (as if to fast-reverse or fast-forward) the video would sync up and start playing normally.

Comment: I've seen this same message pop up when iTunes is playing a video. The one in iTunes doesn't freeze. When I get this message from my app the videos are not exhibiting the black screen and no playback you are describing.